# Execute MVVMCross value converter logic on UI thread

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, ui-thread, mvxbind

I am working on a Xamarin.iOS project, and have a MVVMCross value converter that takes a file extension string and returns the corresponding file icon as an `UIImage`.

This converter is used in a file list. I found that when I'm scrolling the list, as soon as the `MvxTableViewCell` is recycled, the UI converter is often invoked in the background thread for the recycled cell, making my code to throw an error complaining calling a UIKit method from a background thread.

It looks like in the latest version of MVVMCross, the old `IMvxMainThreadDispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction` method is obsolete. The documentation recommends to use `IMvxMainThreadAsyncDispatcher.ExecuteOnMainThreadAsync` method.

However, this method returns a `Task` with no generic type. This obviously can't work with the `Convert` method of the value converter which expects the `UIImage`.

Is there a way to configure MVVMCross to always invoke the converter on UI thread?

**Update:**

Take the following code example:

```
public class FileIconConverter : MvxValueConverter<string, UIImage>
{
    protected override UIImage Convert(string fileExtension, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // When this is called, it could be in a background thread.
        // Since UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl requires to be called
        // on the UI thread, it would throw the UIKitThreadAccessException.
        return UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename("/tmp/generic" + fileExtension)).Icons[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not added any code here all I can do is give you a bit of speculative advice.

What you can do is use the `InvokeOnMainThread` method of Xamarin.iOS

When you check the Xamarin.iOS documentation on [Working with the UI Thread in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/ios-ui/ui-thread)

You can see that you use this method to make the changes that are supposed to be made on the UI

```
InvokeOnMainThread ( () => {
// manipulate UI controls
});
```

### Update

First of all, if you check the code for `IMvxMainThreadDispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction` at the [MvvmCross's Git](https://git.gloriumdev.com/mshpotenko/MvvmCross/blob/083ced055c0fcf8c07068dbf666732f421fd6d98/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/Touch/Views/MvxTouchUIThreadDispatcher.cs) it is internally calling the same API!

So what you can do to your existing code is something like

```
public class FileIconConverter : MvxValueConverter<string, UIImage>
{
protected override UIImage Convert(string fileExtension, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    UIImage image;
    IMvxMainThreadAsyncDispatcher.ExecuteOnMainThreadAsync(()=>{

    image=UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl
               (NSUrl.FromFilename("/tmp/generic" + fileExtension)).Icons[0];


  });
    return image;
 }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your advice. The problem I'm facing is actually inside the value converter. I have updated my question to include some sample code to better illustrate the issue.

Comment: The problem with `InvokeOnMainThread` method is that, 1 it's not available in the value converter context because it is a method in the `NSObject` class, and 2 it won't be able to return the value in the `Convert` method in the value converter.

Comment: You can use the `UIApplication.SharedApplication` to use the method, any way Check my updated answer in some time

Comment: Thanks! Both your suggestions work. I ended up using `UIApplication.SharedApplication.InvokeOnMainThread`, just in case MVVMCross updates the behaviour of `ExecuteOnMainThreadAsync` to be truly asynchronous in the future. Although I'm a bit concerned on the performance since it causes a thread switch for each item in my file list.

Comment: Well, it's still better than being synchronous so I guess that is fine. Anyway, good luck and feel free to get back in case of issues.